# SHA1 base64 algorithm in javascript and C#

Tags: c#, javascript, sha1

I'm running some tests comparing the sha1 algorithm implemented in javascript - got from http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/ - with its implementation in C#.

Using C# to get the hash for {'method':'people.get'} I'm using this statement:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{'method':'people.get'}")));
```

which gives me `Qy95a0ShZqhbNdt6IF8qNf72jX0=`

In javascript I get almost the same: `Qy95a0ShZqhbNdt6IF8qNf72jX0` using the statement:

```
b64_sha1("{'method':'people.get'}");
```

In the javascript case, the hash doesn't end with a equal (=) sign.

Can this difference cause me troubles in authenticating against a server?

In my case, as many of you may know, the sentence I'm reckoning the hash goes inside the http body and the server will check it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would depend on the receiver but try decoding your result from the javascript with C# and you'll get an exception. The = sign is there to pad the result to the correct length.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Ok, based on that information I saw now that the = sign, as you pointed out, is used for padding the message. Thanks

Comment: @Andres: You can update line 15 of the `sha1.js` file from pajhome.org.uk to use `=` as the padding character.

Comment: Yes, while I was writing the my own answer you were writing this remark. Thanks :)

Comment: You could strip all = signs at the end befiore comparison (or pad with = signs to the correct length)

Answer (score 4):

The `sha1.js` from the lib I mentioned in my question, has a global variable called `b64pad`, used for the purpose of padding. By default its value is `""`. Changing to `"="` gives the exact hash reckoned by C# API